# Are questions on mathematical etymology off-topic?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

A decade ago, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33175/etymology-of-arccos-arcsin-arctan) was asked about the names of the inverse trigonometric functions. At the time, it received a [Nice Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer), which was accepted, as well as a few other answers and comments. Two days ago, a new user posted another answer which did not address the original question, and which was deleted by 3 [trusted users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). This is all perfectly normal.

But then the original question was [locked](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts), and I cannot understand why.

A locked post does not accept answers, comments, or revisions. It is frozen in time, and can only be unlocked by a moderator. The explanation given on the question is that it is off-topic, but is kept because of historical significance. Which begs the question: *Why is it off-topic to inquire about the names of the inverse trigonometric functions?* It is a direct question that has a straight-forward answer, and knowing the answer will improve your understanding of trigonometry.

The impression of a locked post is that questions of this nature are not welcome on this site. This is in contrast to a [closed post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), which may be on-topic but in need of improvement. Searching for *etymology* on Main gives more than 100 questions about terms and their meaning. Which of these questions are off-topic?

Comment: Etymology is not off-topic per se at Math.SE, but neither does asking about the origins of a math term guarantee that it will be satisfactory as a Question.  By current standards that Question lacks context, though I'm personally inclined to set the bar for context especially low for problems about terminology.  If you view the [Timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/33175/timeline), the sequence of events that led to locking the post will be clarified.  Perhaps Xander will want to give his take.

Comment: Also, there is a Beta SE site devoted to History of Science and Math, [HSM.se] so many historically-based questions are often better placed there.

Comment: That site has been in Beta for at least seven years now. What's that about?

Comment: @hard, there was a little bit of context – OP claimed to be unable to find out anything via Google. That bit of context was edited out by the moderator before locking the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson A lot of sites here have been in beta for a very long time. That is because the criteria for moving a site out of beta are dumb.

Comment: @Gerry Also, Astronomy.SE is 8 years old, and still in beta, but I don't mind. It's rather handy to get the [deletion privilege at 2k](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). ;)

Comment: Also, [matheducators.se] is Beta for quite some time.